# import data from csv file in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, csv

```
ERROR:  could not open file "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\data\Data_copy\student.csv" for reading: No such file or directory
HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
SQL state: 58P01
```

Comment: You really should consider adding an explanation about what you are trying to do, also post any code you have, and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

The error message says it all.

If you use SQL `COPY` command the file to be loaded must be accessible on database server side.

If this is not possible you can use `psql` CLI `\copy` command from the client side because it can access a file on client side.

Example:

```
$ cat t.csv
1,ONE
2,TWO
3,THREE
```

In psql:

```
# \d t
                     Table "public.t"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 x      | integer |           |          | 
 y      | text    |           |          | 


# \copy t from 't.csv' delimiter ',';
COPY 3

# select * from t;
 x |   y   
---+-------
 1 | ONE
 2 | TWO
 3 | THREE
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Can you suggest an example?

Answer (score 0):

Using psql run the following command

```
\copy students from 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\data\Data_copy\student.csv' csv;
```